# How to develop website/application to view in tablet pc?

Tags: tablet-pc

I am developing website and it has to be viewed in tablet pc. Please suggest me what are things to be considered ? technology wise ?

also i need to know what are the tools i need to have to view in my intranet as well as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major issue: in many tablets there is no moving pointer - at least not in a fully usable form. That means that tooltips may not really work, and image maps must be *really* clear, since there is no highlighting until the user actually "clicks" on the link.

Well, actually that's not fully accurate - if the user drags the pointer, it should work like a regular mouse pointer. The problem is that most users avoid dragging and just tap where they want to click directly.

Best piece of advice I can offer: get an actual tablet PC and try browsing your site. Most major issues will be evident almost immediately. If you are able, get a regular tablet/pad user to beta-test your site without trying it out on a desktop PC - they would be able to see issues that you would miss due to your prior knowledge of the site.

Answer (score 1):

The Tablet PC is a standard Windows machine, therefore it has the same browser support as any other Windows box. So there isn't any special technology required.

There are however some design considerations:

First, make sure your layout has plenty of empty space surrounding iterative elements. Crammed pages are tough to navigate with a stylus, and if it is one of the newer models that also support touch it is even more of an issue.

Second, most Tablet PCs are configured with the default font size set for 125%. You want to make sure that your web pages scale correctly and don't end up requiring horizontal scrolling to see the full width of the page.

A second point regarding scaling, Tablet PC supports both Landscape and Portrait modes. In other words, it can be 1024x768 OR 768x1024. You'll want to make sure that your user experience is acceptable in both modes.

Comment: query string will work as it is? because i tested my website now and query strings are not working ?

Comment: It should. There isn't a special "tablet" version of Internet Explorer and it will run standard editions of any other browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc).

Answer (score 0):

One thing i can think of : there is no 'hover' on most tablets, and if it's there at all, likely nobody will see it.

Not all tablets support flash, but they do all support javascript, and Prototype.JS or jQuery will run on them in most cases